# Is there an easy way to make wind?

Tags: scene

Is there an easy way to make wind on objects in blender without physics or bones? I don't want to hand animate anything, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can! Select the object, and add a displace modifier. Set the coordinates to object, and set the target object to a new empty. Animate the empty moving about 2x its distance over 200 frames. Then, for the displace modifier, add a new texture. Make it a banded texture (a wood one with bands), and then distort it a bit. There you go!

[image]