# Graswald add-on: render has less particles than preview

Tags: particles, add-on

I am using the Graswald Add-on with Blender 3.0.1. When I render the image, the number of particles decreases. I cannot find any setting that explains the behavior. Thank you for your help!

[image: Render VS Preview]

Comment: It seems to be something regarding the particle children. The children seem to disappear in the render. Which Graswald version are you using?

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 I see... it's Graswald Pro 1.3.12 thanks

Comment: I'd download GScatter 0.4 from Graswald. It's geometry node-based, safer, and faster than particle systems.   https://www.graswald3d.com/gscatter

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 That was gold!!! Got it, works now. Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing! I'll post my info as an answer so you can close this post.

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 i played around with the addon and its great. But in graswald you could simulate wind. I cannot find any wind Option in gscatter. Is there a workaround or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes there is, my friend! I made a way to do so! Here you go: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260220/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-wind

Comment: I'm having the same problem but I'm already using GScatter - any guidance on what could solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download GScatter 0.4 from Graswald. It's geometry node-based, safer, and faster than particle systems. graswald3d.com/gscatter

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, too.
I solved it by adjusting *Particle Properties > Children > Render Amount*
I increase the number from 0 to 10. The rendering result is almost same as the viewport.